# WiFi is divided into several sub networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My WiFi keeps dividing into sub networks automatically. I am using a TP-Link TL-WR740n router.

Here is a screenshot from my network - these are all my WiFi:

[image]

You can see my network appears so many times with the numbers incremented automatically. I have tried everything: resetting, disabling, setting a strong password, but nothing works.

This only happens on my Laptop and not on my phone.

Any thoughts on the cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: My best guess is your WiFi [read about Caesar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule) and wants to conquer the world.

Comment: Try to re-install the WiFi driver in your Laptop.

Comment: Maybe an updated driver too... (but I've had bad luck with tp-link and "reliable functionality" before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with removing all the networks that Windows remembers; Go to Start click Control Panel,  in the search box type wireless, then go to  Manage wireless networks. Remove all the of your old home Wireless network, your current networks and any networks that you no longer use.
Then log into your router change the SSID of your wireless network and try to connect again. If that does not help, try to reinstall the drivers for your wireless adapter.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.tp-link.tw/resources/document/TL-WR740N_V5_QIG.pdf

1. connect the hardware
2. config the router
3. use browser to log in https:\tplinkwifi.net

user: admin
password: admin

follow step to install default

method 2
via cd setup wizard

the details please visit web site http://www.tp-link.tw/resources/document/TL-WR740N_V5_QIG.pdf

Comment: We really expect more out of answers then a link to a document. How about quote the relevant information?